# Subsets of $\omega_\alpha$ and $L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$

Tags: set-theory

Under V=L, is it true that all subsets of $\omega_\alpha$ are contained in $L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$? If so, what would be the salient reason as to why its true?

**Reason for asking question:**

It seems to me that for all $\omega_{\alpha} \leq \alpha< \omega_{\alpha+1}$ at least one subset of $\omega_\alpha$ which codes the well-order of $\omega_\alpha$  with order-type $\alpha$ will always be contained in $L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$. My reasoning for why I think it should hold is rather indirect/round-about though.

What I asked above in the primary question seems to be a plausible generalization (obviously just based upon guess) of what I wrote in previous paragraph (and hence the reason for asking whether it holds or not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is why GCH holds when V=L.

More generally, if V=L then $L_\kappa=H_\kappa$ for any cardinal $\kappa$ (where $H_\kappa = \{x: |\operatorname{trcl}(x)| < \kappa\}$), so we also have, e.g. all subsets of $L_{\omega_\alpha}$ are in $L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}$

The usual argument is via the condensation lemma. Let $X\subseteq \omega_\alpha.$ $X\in L_\beta$ for some limit ordinal $\beta,$ and let $M$ be an elementary submodel of $L_\beta$ with $|M|=\aleph_\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha\cup\{X\}\subseteq M.$ Then by the condensation lemma, there is some $\gamma < \omega_{\alpha+1}$ such that the Mostowski collapse of $M$ is $\pi(M)=L_\gamma.$ Since $\omega_\alpha\subseteq M,$ the Mostowski collapse fixes $\omega_\alpha$ point-wise and so $\pi(X)=X,$ and thus $X\in L_\gamma.$ So $X\in L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}.$

Comment: +1 - beat me to it!

Comment: @Noah: One may think you're an egg... you keep getting beaten.